# Performing an OR of two Mongoid "any_in" queries

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

If I have two queries that look like:

```
Store.any_in(:store_id => @user.stores_followed)
Store.any_in(:store_id => @category.stores)
```

How do I join these into an OR using any_of? I tried this and it doesn't.
I tried

```
Store.any_of({:store_id.any_in => @user.stores_followed}, 
  {:store_id.any_in => @category.stores})
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it isn't full supported in Mongoid, so I had to do:

```
Store.any_of({"store_id" => { "$in" => @user.stores_followed}}, {"store_id" => 
   {"$in" => (:store_id => @category.stores)}})
```

Answer (score 5):

You pass an $or query an array of $in conditions like so:

```
Store.or( { :store_id.in => @user.stores_followed }, { :store_id.in => @category.stores } )
```

Answer (score 1):

[`any_in`](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#any_in) accepts an array of OR values using the [`$in`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) operator.

```
ids = @user.stores_followed.map(&:id) + @category.stores.map(&:id)
Store.any_in(:store_id => ids)
```